# What does wattage of amplifier corresponds to?

Tags: electric-guitar, amplifiers

What does wattage of amplifier corresponds to? Does more wattage means more volume or high gain?

Comment: There are two unrelated questions, please ask one question at a time :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to predict the loudness of an amp based on description](http://music.stackexchange.com/questions/6253/how-to-predict-the-loudness-of-an-amp-based-on-description)

Comment: Sir pls answer then all i have many questions

Comment: It would be better if you asked 3 separate questions:
1) What does the wattage of an amplifier mean;
2) How does the sound of a neck pickup differ from a bridge pickup;
3) What sort of amplifiers suit blues rock and heavy metal genres.  Then you can get a specific answer for each question.

Comment: @MattJones It should be noted that the third question is borderline off-topic. Also it doesn't have a solid answer besides, "pretty much any amp can be used for any genre."

Comment: @ToddWilcox I had an amp once that couldn't be used for *any* genre...

Comment: There are too many different questions in this question that are unrelated so asking them as the same question doesn't make sense.

Comment: I've edited out the other two questions. Please ask them separately.

Answer (score 5):

The rated output power of a guitar amp doesn't really tell you much. It has nothing to do with how much distortion you can get from an amp. It is only slightly related to how loud an amp is. Some amps with a lower output power can get louder than other amps with higher output power.

The only thing the output power really tells you is how far you can make what size speakers move. So an amp with more power can power more speakers and make them move farther. That seems like it's the same as being louder, but loudness is actually pretty complicated and is not just about moving a lot of air.

Comment: -assuming the speakers are identical, with the same efficiency, in the same enclosurers.  Also bear in mind that a 100 watt amp is *theoretically* only half as loud again as a 50 watt, everything else being equal...